# Suddenly every javascript file line 1: Chinese characters in browser console

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I have just experienced this mind boggling thing.

I was coding in my javascript project, when suddenly after the refresh I get a
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL for every line 1 of every javascript file.
(Even the minified ones which I have NEVER touched)

What are these characters? random 特⁶㈮ㄮ〠簠⡣⤠㈰.

This literally happened from one second to the other.

Now, I deleted the contents of one of my javascript files completely and the error dissapears.
As soon as I write "va" I get Uncaught ReferenceError: 癡 is not defined

It seems that my javascript files are interpreted with the wrong character encoding? 
I checked all my files and they are UTF-8 encoded.

What is going on. Please help :/

P.s. This happens on Safari and Chrome

Thanks,

Marc

Comment: what is the file you deleted the contents of to make the error disappear? and what were you doing before this started?

Comment: The file I deleted was a javascript file. One of the 5 I have in my project. I am translating a website to russian at the moment. So I am fiddiling around with russian characters in my javascript and html code.

Comment: I have made progress with this strange thing. The problem is that I have cyrillic characters in my javascript. Which the browser has problems with. Now, I have a line in my code wich is document.getElementById(id).innerText = "Наше агентство". Ok, this is displayed as random garbage on screen. HOWEVER! I started changing the charset on my javascript tag and suddenly THE SAME ERROR!.. what happened? well in my browsers console I can see that my javascript is now reading the cyrillic string! But in the process it interprets the rest of the file as chinese. GO FIGURE!

Comment: Also deleting browser cache will force the browser to forget about this and it will interpret the javascript correctly again